# find the last item but N in a stream w/o storing n items

Tags: stream

Suppose there is a stream of data arriving, D(0), D(1), D(2), .... When D(i) comes, I want to know D(i - N). The most straight forward way is to store the most recent N items and keep updating them upon arrival of new data. But the problem is N can be large so that there is no enough memory to store them. Is there anyway to achieve this by storing much less items than N? A constant of M << N of spaces are preferred? Thanks in advance.

Comment: N is fixed given an application. But it is relatively large compared to memory available. Specifically, I need N around 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I can see, unless there is some regularity in the data that you can exploit. If the data are completely random (such that no element can be inferred from the others), then a choice of not saving element *k* will make it impossible to reproduce that element in iteration *k + N*.

Instead, consider:

- Can you reduce *N*?
- Can you store information on disk or (if you are in an embedded environment) on a slower, cheaper form of memory?
- Is there some pattern in the data? If there is e.g. a repeating pattern, you can utilize that, or if there is some mathematical relationship between the numbers, perhaps some formula can aid in reconstructing one number from others. Even if there is no perceptible pattern, perhaps you could use some compression algorithm to reduce the data size?
- Is there some limitation to the data, e.g. every number is between 0 and 255? If so, you could perhaps reduce the storage requirements.

(What is the application of this, by the way?)

Comment: I'm estimating the quantile of e2e delay in a sensor network with [P2 algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.74.2672&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Since I only care about the e2e delay for the most recent N items, I'm moving a window of size N as e2e delay samples keep coming. As a sample D(i) comes, I put it in the window and evict D(i - N), both logically since I cannot afford to save the entire window of samples.

Comment: @sinoTrinity: Hm - I'm not good at statistics, but isn't the point of the article that with the algorithm they describe, you only need to store a few values, not all _N_ of them? (The price you pay for storing only a few values is that you only get an approximate value for the quantiles - my statement that you need to store all values assumed that you wanted an exact result that depended on all _N_ values.)

Comment: Yes, it's all estimation. P2 estimates the quantile for ALL the samples seen so far. It includes all the history. But I want to estimate quantile for recent N samples only because what happens long long ago may not be meaningful at all.

Comment: @sinoTrinity: Ah, now I think I understand - so you need to store the values because you want to somehow "remove" each element from the estimate when the element is too old? In that case, I think my original argument applies: you cannot restore the value without actually saving it. So unless there is a version of the P2 algorithm which is specifically tailored for this scenario, I think you need to store all the _N_ values.

Comment: @sinoTrinity: However, consider this possible approach: rather than having a sliding window of _N_ elements and trying to adjust the estimate for that window, run the P2 algorithm for the first _N_ elements to obtain quantiles. Then, _restart_ the algorithm and run it on the next _N_ elements. That way, you'll only get updated quantiles after every _N_ elements. If that is too little, but you can live with having updates after every _M_ elements, run _N / M_ instances of the algorithm, each starting _M_ elements after the previous one and resetting every _M_. Memory consumption: _5 * N / M_.